# How do I make skirting boards removable?

Tags: painting, trim, trim-carpentry

I have been thinking about how to make a room easy to repaint, if I could remove the skirting boards with ease, then paint them away from the carpet and paint the walls without having to mask the skirting boards it would save a lot of effort.

However how do I make skirting boards removable without them looking “cheap” and how do I hide any imperfections in the flatness of the wall without corking between the 
skirting boards and wall.

(PS, most walls here are built with brick with a plaster finish)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

1. Cut skirting board to size
2. Attached it to the wall with glue-on hook and loop tape (often called by the brand name Velcro®)
3. Cut and place a thinner quarter round or ogee molding along the top edge of the skirting, conforming it to the curves in the wall
4. Attach top molding with glue and brads, only to the skirting, being carefull not to get any glue on walls (masking tape or waxed paper can be used)
5. After glue dries, remove skirting/moulding unit
6. Paint skirting/moulding unit
7. Reinstall.

Comment: Could also try UGlu

Comment: @Monso I don't think UGlu is easily removable.

Comment: It's stronger than a hook and loop connection but still easily capable to separate and actual removal is even easier, you can literally roll it off.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a system called [Simtrim](http://simtrim.ca/), and depending on your existing skirting/baseboard you may  be able to re-use your existing skirt moulding.  You will need to use a router and router table to cut in a 3/4" dovetail groove in the back of the moulding of your choice, or possibly use your existing moulding, if it meets the criteria and then using the Simtrim male and female snap components you will be able to make your skirting removable and replaceable.

Comment: It is for sale oursite of the USA?

Comment: Please review the help section about [overt self-promotion](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)